# RESOLVED: Locally installed langflow PromptTemplate does not display prompt variables

Tags: langchain

I am testing the "Basic Chat with Prompt and History" example on my locally installed langflow. But failed with the first step of editing "PromptTemplate".
In the locally installed langflow, the PromptTemplate editing window (as below), the prompt variables quoted by "{" not highlighted at the bottom. But the online version of langflow displayed the prompt variables correctly as illustrated below.

With this problem. There are no prompt variables displayed on the promptTemplate panel.

- Versions:

  - langflow 0.2.7
  - python 3.11.4

This maybe caused by the low version of langflow. I am trying the latest langflow 0.4.1.

## locally installed langflow

- the edit prompt window does not display the prompt variables at the bottom

[image]

- no prompt variables be displayed on the promptTemplate panel

[image]

## online version of langflow

- prompt variables are highlighted in the edit prompt window

[image]

- prompt variables are displayed on the promptTemplate panel

[image]

## update

- after installing the latest version of langflow, the problem is resolved. In case anyone encounter the exact same problem in the future, I keep this thread here.